# Looping through variables in a dataframe to find summary stats

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I don't know much about R, and I have a variables in a dataframe that I am trying to calculate some stats for, with the hope of writing them into a csv. I have been using a basic for loop, like this:

```r
for(i in x) {
    mean(my_dataframe[,c(i)], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

where x is colnames(my_dataframe)

Not every variable is numeric - but when I add a print to the loop, this works fine - it just prints means when applicable, and NA when not. However, when I try to assign this loop to a value (means <- for....), it produces an empty list. Similarly, when I try to directly write the results to a csv, I get an empty csv. Does anyone know why this is happening/how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

this should work for you. you don't need a loop. just use the summary() function.

```
summary(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` or `sapply` for this sort of thing. e.g.

`sapply(my_dataframe, mean)`

will get you all the means. You can also give it your own function e.g.

`sapply(my_dataframe, function(x) sum(x^2 + 2)/4 - 9)`

If all variables are not numeric you can use `summarise_if` from `dplyr` to get the results just for the numeric columns.

```
require(dplyr)
my_dataframe %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

Without `dplyr`, you could do

```
sapply(my_dataframe[sapply(my_dataframe, is.numeric)], mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop executes the code inside, but it doesn't put any results together. To do that, you need to create an object to hold the results and explicitly assign each one:

```
my_means = rep(NA, ncol(my_dataframe)
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    my_means[i] = mean(my_dataframe[, x[i], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Note that I have also changed your loop to use `i = 1, 2, 3, ...` instead of each name.

`sapply`, as shown in another answer, is a nice shortcut that does the loop and combines the results for you, so you don't need to worry about pre-allocating the result object. It's also smart enough to iterate over columns of a data frame by default.

```
my_means_2 = sapply(my_dataframe, mean, na.rm = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a reproducible example the next time you post a question.

`Input` is how I imagine your data would look like.

Input:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
input <- flights %>% select(origin, air_time, carrier, arr_delay)

input
# A tibble: 336,776 x 4
   origin air_time carrier arr_delay
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 EWR        227. UA            11.
 2 LGA        227. UA            20.
 3 JFK        160. AA            33.
 4 JFK        183. B6           -18.
 5 LGA        116. DL           -25.
 6 EWR        150. UA            12.
 7 EWR        158. B6            19.
 8 LGA         53. EV           -14.
 9 JFK        140. B6            -8.
10 LGA        138. AA             8.
# ... with 336,766 more rows
```

The way I see it, there are 2 ways to do it:

1. Use `summarise_all()`

`summarise_all()` will summarise all your columns, including those that are not numeric.

Method:

```
input %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  origin air_time carrier arr_delay
   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1     NA     151.      NA      6.90

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(origin, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(carrier, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

You will get a result and a warning if you were to use this method.

2. Use `summarise_if`

summarise only numeric columns. You can avoid from getting any error this way.

Method:

```
input %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  air_time arr_delay
     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     151.      6.90
```

You can then create a NA column for others